# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Cinnamon is currently running without video hardware acceleration

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, cinnamon

I am new to using Ubuntu Desktop and I am trying out Cinnamon for the first time, but every time I connect to my desktop, I am getting a warning stating that I should check my video drivers because I am running without hardware acceleration.

My GPU is a Nvidia 2080 Ti using nvidia-driver-520-open drivers. My CPU is a Ryzen 5600 with no integrated graphics. I am using xrdp to connect to this system remotely over my LAN. The computer has a monitor plugged in, but I intend to use it headless most of the time.

I tried all of the solutions I could find to troubleshoot this problem, but haven't had any luck. My packages and kernel are all reporting as up to date.

I tried adding the following to **/etc/modules** and UEFI is disabled:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

nvidia
nvidia-drm
nvidia-modeset
```

```
> nvidia-smi
Mon Nov 21 01:54:50 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.56.06    Driver Version: 520.56.06    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:07:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 41%   25C    P8     1W / 260W |     15MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1968      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  9MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2243      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
> glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
```

```
>nvidia-smi -a

==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                                 : Mon Nov 21 02:11:30 2022
Driver Version                            : 520.56.06
CUDA Version                              : 11.8

Attached GPUs                             : 1
GPU 00000000:07:00.0
    Product Name                          : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
    Product Brand                         : GeForce
    Product Architecture                  : Turing
    Display Mode                          : Disabled
    Display Active                        : Disabled
    Persistence Mode                      : Disabled
    MIG Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    Accounting Mode                       : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size           : 4000
    Driver Model
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    Serial Number                         : 0323918078423
    GPU UUID                              : GPU-0d31d5e5-a0a2-7e48-1d70-7ac852c728bc
    Minor Number                          : 0
    VBIOS Version                         : 90.02.0B.00.0E
    MultiGPU Board                        : No
    Board ID                              : 0x700
    GPU Part Number                       : 900-1G150-2530-000
    Module ID                             : 0
    Inforom Version
        Image Version                     : G001.0000.02.04
        OEM Object                        : 1.1
        ECC Object                        : N/A
        Power Management Object           : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    GSP Firmware Version                  : N/A
    GPU Virtualization Mode
        Virtualization Mode               : None
        Host VGPU Mode                    : N/A
    IBMNPU
        Relaxed Ordering Mode             : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                               : 0x07
        Device                            : 0x00
        Domain                            : 0x0000
        Device Id                         : 0x1E0710DE
        Bus Id                            : 00000000:07:00.0
        Sub System Id                     : 0x12A410DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                       : 3
                Current                   : 1
            Link Width
                Max                       : 16x
                Current                   : 16x
        Bridge Chip
            Type                          : N/A
            Firmware                      : N/A
        Replays Since Reset               : 0
        Replay Number Rollovers           : 0
        Tx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
        Rx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
    Fan Speed                             : 41 %
    Performance State                     : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                              : Active
        Applications Clocks Setting       : Not Active
        SW Power Cap                      : Not Active
        HW Slowdown                       : Not Active
            HW Thermal Slowdown           : Not Active
            HW Power Brake Slowdown       : Not Active
        Sync Boost                        : Not Active
        SW Thermal Slowdown               : Not Active
        Display Clock Setting             : Not Active
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                             : 11264 MiB
        Reserved                          : 244 MiB
        Used                              : 17 MiB
        Free                              : 11002 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                             : 256 MiB
        Used                              : 4 MiB
        Free                              : 252 MiB
    Compute Mode                          : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                               : 0 %
        Memory                            : 0 %
        Encoder                           : 0 %
        Decoder                           : 0 %
    Encoder Stats
        Active Sessions                   : 0
        Average FPS                       : 0
        Average Latency                   : 0
    FBC Stats
        Active Sessions                   : 0
        Average FPS                       : 0
        Average Latency                   : 0
    Ecc Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            SRAM Correctable              : N/A
            SRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A
            DRAM Correctable              : N/A
            DRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A
        Aggregate
            SRAM Correctable              : N/A
            SRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A
            DRAM Correctable              : N/A
            DRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC                    : N/A
        Double Bit ECC                    : N/A
        Pending Page Blacklist            : N/A
    Remapped Rows                         : N/A
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp                  : 22 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp                 : 94 C
        GPU Slowdown Temp                 : 91 C
        GPU Max Operating Temp            : 89 C
        GPU Target Temperature            : 84 C
        Memory Current Temp               : N/A
        Memory Max Operating Temp         : N/A
    Power Readings
        Power Management                  : Supported
        Power Draw                        : 1.11 W
        Power Limit                       : 260.00 W
        Default Power Limit               : 260.00 W
        Enforced Power Limit              : 260.00 W
        Min Power Limit                   : 100.00 W
        Max Power Limit                   : 320.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                          : 300 MHz
        SM                                : 300 MHz
        Memory                            : 405 MHz
        Video                             : 540 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
        Memory                            : N/A
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
        Memory                            : N/A
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                          : 2160 MHz
        SM                                : 2160 MHz
        Memory                            : 7000 MHz
        Video                             : 1950 MHz
    Max Customer Boost Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                        : N/A
        Auto Boost Default                : N/A
    Voltage
        Graphics                          : N/A
    Processes
        GPU instance ID                   : N/A
        Compute instance ID               : N/A
        Process ID                        : 1968
            Type                          : G
            Name                          : /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
            Used GPU Memory               : 9 MiB
        GPU instance ID                   : N/A
        Compute instance ID               : N/A
        Process ID                        : 2243
            Type                          : G
            Name                          : /usr/bin/gnome-shell
            Used GPU Memory               : 4 MiB
```

```
>inxi -Fxxxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-53-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME B550-PLUS v: Rev X.0x
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2803
    date: 04/27/2022
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600 bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled
    arch: Zen 3 rev: 2 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 3 MiB L3: 32 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3697 high: 4450 min/max: 2200/4467 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 4126 2: 3554 3: 3471 4: 3560 5: 3552 6: 4450 7: 3581 8: 3467
    9: 3559 10: 3569 11: 3556 12: 3921 bogomips: 83996
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] driver: nvidia
    v: 520.56.06 pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: none
    empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, HDMI-A-1, Unknown-1 bus-ID: 07:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:1e07 class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 compositor: gnome-shell driver: X:
    loaded: nouveau unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: nvidia
    display-ID: :10.0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3440x1440 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 910x381mm (35.8x15.0")
    s-diag: 987mm (38.8")
  Monitor-1: rdp0 res: 3440x1440 hz: 50 size: N/A
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.0.5
    direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU102 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 07:00.1
    chip-ID: 10de:10f7 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 09:00.4 chip-ID: 1022:1487 class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-53-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: ASUSTeK PRIME B450M-A driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 port: f000 bus-ID: 06:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp6s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 15.46 TiB used: 2.42 TiB (15.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WD Blue SN570 1TB
    size: 931.51 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: 234100WD temp: 27.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD80EAZZ-00BKLB0
    size: 7.28 TiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 5640 serial: <filter>
    rev: 0A80 scheme: GPT
  ID-3: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD80EAZZ-00BKLB0
    size: 7.28 TiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 5640 serial: <filter>
    rev: 0A80 scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.32 GiB used: 168.76 GiB (18.4%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 11.3 MiB (2.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  Message: No sensor data found. Is lm-sensors configured?
Info:
  Processes: 417 Uptime: 25m wakeups: 1 Memory: 62.72 GiB
  used: 3.63 GiB (5.8%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11 Packages: 2407 apt: 2374 snap: 33 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: This irritates me: `OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1 256 bits)..` What does `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"` say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nvidia driver ist not working:

```
    Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X:
    loaded: nouveau unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: nvidia`. Try to switch
```

So you might need a XorgConf (assuming you are running XServer and not wayland) like this:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "nvidia"
  Driver "nvidia"
  BusID "PCI:07:00.0"
EndSection
```